# Tools needed for drilling holes into the wood?

Tags: wood, drilling, holes

I just need to drive few holes into the wood to make a DIY bathroom storage. But I am facing some problem to do that without any tools. Can anyone sort out the required tools for that?

Comment: Why can't you use tools? What things do you have available?

Comment: I think Bailey is saying that she has no tools and what tools will she need to drill these holes. A portable electric drill and a bit of the correct size, but without more details or restrictions I can't be any more specific

Answer (score 2):

First you need a drill. This can be a hand drill like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00004UDKT/ref=asc_df_B00004UDKT52255485/?tag=googshopuk-21&creative=22110&creativeASIN=B00004UDKT&linkCode=df0&hvadid=226606326869&hvpos=1o4&hvnetw=g&hvrand=1713181915909916511&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046058&hvtargid=pla-486293491837&th=1&psc=1) or an electric drill.

Then you need suitable drill bit.

There are a few different types for different materials and hole sizes:

Twist drills:

[image: Twist drill]

This is really the "standard" drill bit which most people will think of first. They can be used on a bunch of different materials (generally metal, wood, plastics) and they don't have anything special about the tip - it's just two cutting edges at an angle. Depending on the material it can be hard to keep this type of bit centred when starting a hole.

Brad point drills:

[image: Brad point drill]

These are a good "all round" bit for drilling small sized holes in wood. they have a point on the end which keeps the bit centred as you are drilling through the material. I'd typically use these for anything up to about a 12mm hole, though you can get larger.

Auger drills:

[image: Auger drill]

These have a different point type, in fact the point is like a little screw which draws itself into the wood. The spiral of the drill has a wider cut-out which makes them good at pulling chips out of holes. This means you can drill quite large (wide) and deep holes in one go. I've seen these go up to 30mm or wider.

Spade bits:

[image: Spade drill bits]

These are used for drilling large holes quickly. They're typically not for drilling very deep because they have no chip clearance spirals. They're generally best used in a power drill because they work best at high speed.

Forstner bits:

[image: Forstner bit]

This is typically used for drilling shallow but wide holes quickly. Again it's usually best to use these in a power drill as they work best at high-ish speeds and you'd find it hard work with a hand drill. These are often used to drill holes to take things like kitchen cupboard doors as the type of hinges used fit into a circular recess.

You may also need a countersink bit:

[image: Countersinks]

These are used to give a hole a "bevel" or angle to one side, usually to accept a countersunk screw head.

I'm sure there are other kinds of drill available but these are the ones most often used in woodworking. Typically if you're stuck you can do an internet search for "what kind of drill bit should I use for [x]" and find something useful.

Answer (score 0):

To drill holes you will need a drill and a bit of the correct size.

You will optionally also need something to measure with to locate where they should be and something to mark this location on your work piece.